# Schengen visa apply Singapore France embassy

Tags: schengen-visas, applications, singapore

I applied for a visa in France embassy consulate, they  took my passport and documents and biometric. After 24 hours I checked my status.
The decision concerning your application has been reached.

When I get my visa please answer me?

Answer (score 3):

No-one can answer that, or tell you whether the status message means your visa has been approved or refused. You’ll just have to wait it out, unfortunately.